# Alternating Odd and Even Comment Styles with the new WordPress 2.7 Comments Loop

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

With the new WordPress 2.7 Comments Loop, I know you can simply add .odd and .even to your CSS to get alternating styles, which I've done:

```
.odd { background: #ccc; color: #000; }
.even { background: #bbb; color: #000; }
```

However, I have two different backgrounds - a light and a dark one - that the user can choose from the options panel. Therefore I need two different versions of the odd and even classes so I can have different colours for each, as the above background colours look nice against the light background but not so good against the dark one.

But with the 2.7 Comments Loop, the odd and even classes aren't actually there in the code. If they were, I'd have done something like this:

```
$background = get_option('mytheme_background');
if ($background== "option1") { echo '<div class="odd-dark">'; } 
if ($background== "option1") { echo '<div class="even-dark">'; }
if ($background== "option2") { echo '<div class="odd-light">'; } 
if ($background== "option2") { echo '<div class="even-light">'; }
```

So with .odd and .even not actually being there in the code, how can I go about having two different .odd and .even versions in the CSS?

Answer (score 0):

A belated response but for anyone else stumbling upon it...

A far easier solution to this problem would be to look at it the other way around.  Instead of adding theme-option names to each and every required html element, simply add a single class name in a **containing** element.

For instance in the given example you could add *"dark"* to the list of classes in the document `body` - then all style-attributes pertaining to the "dark theme" would be declared like so:

```
body.dark div.odd  { ... }
body.dark div.even { ... }
```

This way you:

- Have less *bloat* in your markup
- Make your CSS logic more readable
- Ensure a consistent naming convention